# watch for changes in React and update state on file add or delete in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am working on an Electron app that uses React on the front end.  The app will display files from a couple folders.  Then it will allow the user to delete files or copy files to another folder with some buttons.  I have figured out how to get the files deleted or copied using buttons.  But I can't figure out how to update the GUI after the files have been deleted or copied.  I've been following this tutorial: https://medium.com/jspoint/working-with-files-i-o-in-an-electron-application-b4d2de403f54

Here is the relevant portion of my backend `electron.js`:

```js
// Module to control the application lifecycle and the native browser window.
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  protocol,
  nativeTheme,
  ipcMain,
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

const io = require("../electron/io");

// Create the native browser window.
function createWindow() {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    resizable: false,
    // Set the path of an additional "preload" script that can be used to
    // communicate between node-land and browser-land.
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  nativeTheme.themeSource = "dark";

  // return list of current front end files
  ipcMain.handle("app:get-current-FE-files", () => {
    return io.getFiles("C:/test");
  });

  // return list of previous front end files
  ipcMain.handle("app:get-previous-FE-files", () => {
    return io.getFiles("C:/test-previous-files");
  });

  ipcMain.handle("app:delete-all-folder-contents", (event, folder) => {
    // console.log({ event });
    // console.log({ folder });
    let folderWithFiles = '';
    if (folder === 'prodorchtest-previous-folder') {
      folderWithFiles = 'C:/test-previous-files';
    }
    return io.deleteAllFilesInFolder(folderWithFiles);
  });

  ipcMain.handle("app:copy-all-folder-contents", (event, fromTo) => {
    console.log({ fromTo })
    if (fromTo === 'prodorchtest-to-previous-folder') {
      return io.copyFilesBetweenFolders('C:/test', 'C:/test-previous-files');
    }
  });

  // In production, set the initial browser path to the local bundle generated
  // by the Create React App build process.
  // In development, set it to localhost to allow live/hot-reloading.
  const appURL = app.isPackaged
    ? url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true,
      })
    : "http://localhost:3006";
  mainWindow.loadURL(appURL);

  io.watchFiles(mainWindow);
```

Then in `io.js`, this is what `watchFiles` looks like:

```js
// watch files from the application's storage directory
exports.watchFiles = (win) => {
  const prevFEFolder = 'C:/test-previous-files';

  // chokidar.watch(prevFEFolder).on("unlink", (filepath) => {
  //   console.log('unlink called with: ', filepath)
  //   //win.webContents.send("app:delete-file", path.parse(filepath).base);
  // });
  chokidar.watch(prevFEFolder).on('add', (path) => {
    console.log({ path });
    win.webContents.send("app:add-file", path);
  });
};
```

Here is my `preload.js`:

```js
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

// As an example, here we use the exposeInMainWorld API to expose the browsers
// and node versions to the main window.
// They'll be accessible at "window.versions".
process.once("loaded", () => {
  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("versions", process.versions);
});

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("fsInfo", {
  getCurrentFEDirContents: () => ipcRenderer.invoke("app:get-current-FE-files"),
  getPreviousFEDirContents: () =>
    ipcRenderer.invoke("app:get-previous-FE-files"),
});

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("fsActions", {
  deleteAllFolderContents: (folder) => ipcRenderer.invoke("app:delete-all-folder-contents", folder),
  copyAllFolderContents: (fromTo) => ipcRenderer.invoke("app:copy-all-folder-contents", fromTo),
});
```

I'm not sure if that is where I should be adding my frontend functionality to watch for the file changes or if it should be in `App.js`.

And here is the first part my `App.js`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faArrowRight, faFileImage } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import folder from './img/folder.png';
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary';

// this import causes errors
// const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const App = () => {
  // these state arrays are what I would want to update when changes are made with deleting
  // or copying files
  const [currentFEFiles, setCurrentFEFiles] = useState([]);
  const [previousFEFiles, setPreviousFEFiles] = useState([]);

  // useEffect(() => {

  //   // Listen for the event
  //   ipcRenderer.on('app:add-file', (event, arg) => {
  //     console.log({event, arg})
  //   });

  //   // Clean the listener after the component is dismounted
  //   return () => {
  //     ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners();
  //   };

  // }, []);

  const getTheFiles = async () => {
    try {
      const currentFilelist = await window.fsInfo.getCurrentFEDirContents();
      console.log({ currentFilelist });
      currentFilelist.sort((a, b) =>
        a.isDir < b.isDir ? 1 : b.isDir < a.isDir ? -1 : a.name - b.name
      );
      setCurrentFEFiles(currentFilelist);

      const previousFileList = await window.fsInfo.getPreviousFEDirContents();
      previousFileList.sort((a, b) =>
        a.isDir < b.isDir ? 1 : b.isDir < a.isDir ? -1 : a.name - b.name
      );
      setPreviousFEFiles(previousFileList);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log({ e });
      setCurrentFEFiles([]);
    }
    // setCurrentFEFiles([]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTheFiles();
    //window.fsInfo.getDirContents().then(r => console.log({r}));
    // console.log({ filelist });
  }, []);

  const deleteFolderContents = async (folder) => {
    await window.fsActions.deleteAllFolderContents(folder);
  };

  const copyFolderContents = async (fromTo) => {
    await window.fsActions.copyAllFolderContents(fromTo);
    // maybe this is where I would add some code to update the state?
  };
```

Comment: It is best to keep only UI functionality in the render process. Use your preload script to communicate **actions** between processes. EG: The main process sends a list of files that can be interacted to the render process on page load. Clicking of a specific UI button sends the action (copy / delete) and path (wrapped in an obkect) via IPC to the main process. The main process performs the action, verify's success or failure and sends a response back to the render process. If the file is successfully copied / deleted, update its node in HTML. If the action failed, display appropiate message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be just in the `React` part.

After reviewed your code `App.js`, it seems that your code does not inform `React` to rerender after files change.

The `useEffect` here

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getTheFiles();
    //window.fsInfo.getDirContents().then(r => console.log({r}));
    // console.log({ filelist });
  }, []); // '[]' here means run only once
```

runs only once. It won't refresh your UI everytime your file changes.

Even though you have state arrays changed in `getTheFiles`, the `getTheFiles` got no chance to get reinvoked.

you could try just add `getTheFiles()` in both `deleteFolderContents`, `copyFolderContents` below the `await` line, because those `setXXX` in `getTheFiles` will trigger UI rerender.

```
  const deleteFolderContents = async (folder) => {
    await window.fsActions.deleteAllFolderContents(folder);
    getTheFiles();
  };

  const copyFolderContents = async (fromTo) => {
    await window.fsActions.copyAllFolderContents(fromTo);
    getTheFiles();
  };
```